# libgdx fling point of contact detection

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am able to detect the fling gesture of libgdx using the below snippet

```
@Override
public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "velocity in X direction is : " + velocityX);
    // System.out.println("OSR");
    return true;
}
```

However, how should I detect the point of first contact and the subsequent points during the fling action? I need this because I am applying the fling action on an image on the screen and would like it to move in the respective direction depending on the velocities.

Comment: have you tried using the current pointer position or adding a listener for touch/pointer events?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I added the listerner for touchdown and extended GestureDetector to override touchUp. But does co-ordinate detected by touchUp mean its also the last contact by fling?